# Is Lord Zedd walking around in just a metal codpiece?

Tags: power-rangers

I was perusing DeviantArt and came across some Power Rangers artwork.  (See below.)  My first thought was "He [Lord Zedd] looks naked!"  I'm not sure why I never thought of it before.  Maybe because I could tell it was a rubber suit?

Regardless, now that I think about it, it definitely looks like he's only wearing a codpiece, and a has part(s) of his skeleton showing.  I'm not specifically referring to this piece; you could look at the suit or any image of Zedd and see abotu the same thing.

Is Lord Zedd naked?  Is this some kind of indication of a perverted character* that didn't translate well from Japan?  That leg pose reminds me of many a Bishonen harassing a lead male character in anime.

*Examples include (in no specific order) [Darkness](http://konosuba.wikia.com/wiki/Darkness), [Sunny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Toriko_characters#Sunny), [Levin](https://allthetropes.org/wiki/Tekkaman_Blade/Characters#Levin.2FMaggie), [Hisoka Morow](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Hisoka_Morow), [Kuroko Shirai](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Shirai_Kuroko), or some kind of [Bishonen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bish%C5%8Dnen), or [generic pervert](https://www.japanpowered.com/anime-articles/anime-stereotypes-pervert) ([link](https://www.ranker.com/list/pervert-anime-characters/ranker-anime)).

[image]

[Image source](https://draw4u.deviantart.com/art/Lord-Zedd-282992783).

Comment: I think the more obvious question here is, why isn't everyone else?

Answer (score 8):

That is indeed his bare skin under his skimpy armour. It would appear that his original carapace was burned off during an abortive attempt to use the Zeo Crystal

[image]
<sub><sup>[Mighty Morphin' Power Rangers Album 2016](http://powerrangers.wikia.com/wiki/Mighty_Morphin_Power_Rangers_2016_Annual)</sup></sub>